Difference or Union geometry generators using (sometimes) empty layers in QGIS
I have a geometry generator expression which does some clipping and merging such as the below which works fine when there are features in layers 2 and 3, when there are no features in layers 2 or 3 the expression fails - which is basically understandable but I need a way around it. I have got around this using a CASE WHEN setup that checks for features but this makes the expression very long winded and hard to manage. Is there a better way to be able to avoid problems with empty layers?
combine(
        difference(
        @geometry
        , aggregate('Layer 2','collect',$geometry)
        )
    ,aggregate('Layer 3','collect',$geometry)
    )


Can you use coalesce? Something like coalesce( aggregate('Layer 2','collect',$geometry), st_buffer(st_point(1,1),0.000001)) to return a very small geometry instead of nothing

function coalesce: Returns the first non-NULL value from the expression list.
This function can take any number of arguments. - Looks promising also in other cases buffer(make_point( 0,0),0) makes legit geo

@BERA From testing it seems coalesce sees an empty layer as legit so always returns the aggregate layer even if it is empty.

Can you describe in more detail the processing steps? In your example your differencing Layer 2 with Layer 3 then combining them, I presume to delete overlaps? Do you have many more steps in the full case when query?

@BERA the expression differences the layers geometry with layer 2  then combines the result with layer 3 - This is to allow the user to make non destructive edits to what is displayed for the main layer. In my case the actual geometry displayed for the main layer is the result of some other expressions but I have simplified things for this question.

Maybe you can use a virtual layer instead? select coalesce(st_difference(a.geometry, b.geometry), a.geometry) as geometry from layer1 a left join layer2 b on st_intersects(a.geometry, b.geometry) union select * from layer3

Sadly some of the functions I use in the rest of the expression are not supported by virtual layers and virtual layers don't really work for me until we migrate from geopackages to a DB server. I have dodged the problem for now.
